# Passing bash output as argument to Python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to pass Epoch time as an argument to my Python script but am struggling to figure out a way how. I would like to do something like the following:

```sh
epoch_time="date +%s" # computes Epoch time
./script.py epoch_time
```

I know that technically `epoch_time` would be considered a string there, but is there a way to invoke a command and store its output on one line like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(cmd)` to capture command output. Don't put any spaces around the `=` assignment.

```
epoch_time=$(date +%s)
./script.py "$epoch_time"
```

Or without the variable:

```
./script.py "$(date +%s)"
```

Comment: That seems to work but it is passing `!*` into the Python script, which I assume is a special character. My Python script in this instance is expecting an integer value.

Comment: Ah, just had to remove the quotes. `./script.py $(date +%s)` works for me. Thank you kindly!

Comment: Nope, don't remove the quotes.

Comment: How come? I need an integer, not a string representation of the integer.

Comment: Everything's a string in shell scripts. There are no integer values, only string representations of them. See https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html for details on why expansions should be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who came here looking for a bash command, this works

```
echo "foobar" | xargs -I{} ./script.py {}
```